# Can a massless quark exist?

Tags: standard-model, mass-energy, quarks, confinement

Is there any possible way to extract all the mass of a quark? Probably under extreme Gs  or heat or pressure?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any possible way to extract all the mass of a quark?probably under extreme Gs or heat or pressure?

Not with classical means, like Gs and heat and pressure, because the quarks are elementary particles held together within hadrons because of [QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics) .

Quarks can give up all their energy when quark meets antiquark, as happens in [proton antiproton annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Proton-antiproton_annihilation), where quarks meet antiquarks and annihilate into other particles and finally everything ends up in kinetic energy and radiation. The original quarks have disappeared in the process .

Now the title

> Can a massless quark exist?

Can be answered with : yes, before [symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking#Higgs_mechanism) and the Higgs mechanism, quarks have zero mass. This happens at the very high energies at the [beginning of our present universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang#/media/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg),  10^-32seconds to a microsecond, as far as our physics knowledge takes us.

Comment: How are anti-quarks generated?

Comment: They make up the antiproton, the antiprotons are generated by high energy scatterings of protons on protons. It aint simple